# Add commas to input and output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get the input to be considered as currency and have commas. I have the output showing currency with a decimal but it is missing the comma. I have tried to get these two things working together but I keep running into errors. Any help is appreciated!!

```
      function calculate(){
    var savingsVal = ($('#savingsVal').val());
    var totalSavings = 0;

    if (filterValues(savingsVal)) {
    totalSavings = savingsVal * 0.15;
    }
    $('#totalSavings').val('$' + totalSavings);  
  }

 function filterValues(eVal){
   if (eVal.length == 0)
   {
     $('.errorMessage').text('Insert value');
     $('.equipValCont').addClass('has-error');
     return false;
    }
    else if(!$.isNumeric(eVal)){
      $('.errorMessage').text('Please, enter only numbers');
      $('.equipValCont').addClass('has-error');
      return false;
   } else{
    $('.equipValCont').removeClass('has-error');
    return true;
   }
 }

  $('#calculator').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    calculate();
  });
```

Comment: `I have tried to get these two things working together` - where? I see no attempt at adding `,`

Comment: I took that part off as it was not working. I can re-add what I did if that will help?

Comment: well, SO does require you at least attempt to solve your problem :p

Comment: my apologies I can add what I did on the first attempt

Comment: doesn't matter - you got some answers now, so there's no point in showing non-working code :p

Answer (score 0):

With [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) this is as simple as:

```
var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0');
```

Not sure if you're opposed to using a library here, but numeral.js is wonderful.

Comment: with native Javascript it's just as simple ... `var string = '$' + someNumber.toLocaleString();`

Comment: I am not opposed to a library, I tried the numeral.js but it did not work. But I also did not get any errors.

Comment: Good to know. I rely on numeral pretty heavily in certain projects, easy to forget that there are native ways to do simple things like this.

Comment: though, you MAY want to use `.toLocaleString('en')` to force commas ... because different locales like `de` for example swap the meaning of `.` and `,` i.e. `123.456.789,12`... and Indian's put commas every second number (after the first three) `12,34,56,789.12`

Answer (score 0):

For your validation, instead of checking`else if(!$.isNumeric(eVal)){` use regex to validate your value. You must consider "," as a valid since your currency will allowed "," . below as sample

```
var currencyStr= "1,123.20";
if (/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(currencyStr))
    alert("currency is valid");
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I was unable to get the result. Below is the code I added. I apologize in advance, I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
if (/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(currencyStr))
    alert("currency is valid");
```

to

```
if (/^(\d{0,3})(,\d{0,3})*(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(currencyStr))
    alert("currency is valid");
```

I hope this helps you

**UPDATE**

if you want add the correct commas to output, try something like this:

```js
function formatStr( str ) {
 str = str.replace( /,/g, "" );
 var result = str.match( /^([^\.]+)(\.\d{0,2})?$/ ),
 newStr = "",
 integerStr = result[1] ? result[1] : "",
 floatStr = result[2] ? result[2] : "",
 j = 0;
 for ( var i = integerStr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
  if ( j == 3 ) { 
   newStr = integerStr[i] + "," + newStr;
   j = 1;
  }
  else { 
   newStr = integerStr[i] + newStr;
   j++;
  }
 }
 newStr = newStr + floatStr;
 console.log( newStr );
 return newStr;
}
formatStr( "12.34" );
formatStr( "123" );
formatStr( "1234.56" );
formatStr( "12345.6" );
```

Comment: It gave me the alert that the currency is valid, but it did not add the correct commas to my input or output